# How Can i Arrange a list of integers in python in txt file?

Tags: python

How can I arrange a list of integers in python in txt file?
Example = I am having:

```py
['45 USD\n', '68 USD\n', '32 USD\n', '894 USD\n']
```

I want to arrange them in this order:

```py
['894 USD\n', '68 USD\n', '45 USD\n', '32 USD\n']
```

Comment: How do you want to rearrange them, sorted by descending numbers in the strings?

Comment: This is a list of strings, not integers. Do you want to discard the non-number part and then sort them in descending order?

Comment: It would be better if you could explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: do you also have any problem in getting these values from the txt file or is it just that you want to arrange them in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sort function for this.

```
a=['45 USD\n', '68 USD\n', '32 USD\n', '894 USD\n']

a.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]))

print(a) # ['894 USD\n', '68 USD\n', '45 USD\n', '32 USD\n']
```

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp)

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

If all the strings in the list will have the same format, you could create a lambda function to sort them removing the *"string"* part and casting them to integers, as in:

```py
L = ['45 USD\n', '68 USD\n', '32 USD\n', '894 USD\n']   
print(sorted(L, key=lambda x: int(x[:-6]), reverse=True)) # x[:-6] removes the last 6 characters " USD\n"
```

result being:

```
['894 USD\n', '68 USD\n', '45 USD\n', '32 USD\n']
```

Comment: You should split x instead of using x[:-6] because the unit can be changed.

Comment: _"if all the strings in the list will have the same format..."_

Comment: We were not given an input like that, and I reiterate, this _particular solution_ works if all the strings in the list are expected to have the same format.